# How to set focus to a control in a TreeViewItem when selected

Tags: wpf, treeview, focus, treeviewitem

I have a `TreeView` in which the items are defined by `HierarchicalDataTemplate`s. Each `TreeViewItem` that is created has some `TextBox`es in it. When a `TreeViewItem` is selected I want to set the Keyboard `Focus` to a `TextBox` of the `TreeViewItem` (the `TextBox`has the name `TextBox1`). How can I do this?

Answer (score 5):

There are many ways you can do this. Here is just one of them. Use mine [FocusExtension. IsFocused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356045/set-focus-on-textbox-in-wpf-from-view-model-c-wpf/1356781#1356781) attached property. Bind it to TreeViewItem.IsSelectedProperty if you don't have a ViewModel underneath. Something like

```
<TextBox local:FocusExtension.IsFocused="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}}}" />
```

should work. I typed that from head and didn't check the syntax. Be careful while copy-pasting :).