# Use EventTrigger on a specific key

Tags: wpf, keydown, interaction, eventtrigger

I would like to invoke a command using EventTrigger when a particular key is touched (for example, the spacebar key)

Currently I have:

```
  <i:Interaction.Triggers>
       <i:EventTrigger EventName="KeyDown">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DoCommand}" CommandParameter="{BindingText}"/>
       </i:EventTrigger>
  </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Now how can I specify that this should occur only when the KeyDown occurs with the spacebar?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You would have to build a custom Trigger to handle that:

```
public class SpaceKeyDownEventTrigger : EventTrigger {

    public SpaceKeyDownEventTrigger() : base("KeyDown") {
    }

    protected override void OnEvent(EventArgs eventArgs) {
        var e = eventArgs as KeyEventArgs;
        if (e != null && e.Key == Key.Space)
            this.InvokeActions(eventArgs);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, though I still cannot get it to work. I changed my XAML to use `SpaceKeyDownEventTrigger` (instead of just` EventTrigger`) but `OnEvent` is not entered. Is there anything else I should change in my XAML? Thx again

Comment: @lost_bits1110 - Can you please update your question to include a full example? Are you sure the KeyDown event is firing for the associated control?

Comment: yep in my original post the event is being fired for the associated control, but was happening for every key down event. I would just like for it to happen on a specified key. I added a custom EventTrigger class as you've posted, and simply changed my XAML to replace EventTrigger with SpakeKeyDownEventTrigger, but it looks like I need something more

Comment: okay it works now - my mistake was I forgot to put the 'override' keyword. Thanks!

Comment: @lost_bits1110 - Ah, yeah I had that in there originally also, but corrected my mistake earlier.

Comment: Brilliant.  I am using this since the conventional means of using InputBindings does not seem to work for the DatePicker control, whenever I want to deal with an "Enter Pressed" event.  Using this enables me to work around this apparent limitation.

Answer (score 15):

Another approach would be to use KeyBindings and bind them to your Window, UserControl, FrameworkElement, etc. That will not Trigger a button, but say you have a command "MyCommand" that is called from the button, you could invoke the command from InputBindings.

```
<UserControl.InputBindings>
   <KeyBinding Command="{Binding Path=ApplyCommand}" Key="Enter"/>
   <KeyBinding Command="{Binding Path=NextPage}" Modifiers="Ctrl" Key="Left"/>
</UserControl.InputBindings>

<StackPanel> 
    <Button IsDefault="True" Content="Apply">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
           <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
               <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=ApplyCommand}" />                            
           </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </Button>
 </StackPanel>
```

You could also bind these KeyBindings to a TextBox.

Comment: I prefer this solution as it allows me to keep almost all of my code in the xaml for handling the key interactions. I'm currently working on a TextBlock/TextBox editiable label and doing it this way allowed me to create a new editable style I can apply to any label going forward. Simple and elegant. Thanks Kalisohn!!

Comment: This worked for me. I was creating triggers for a '+' and '-' symbols. Take my updoot!

Answer (score 1):

I like the idea with a custom trigger but I didn't managed to make it work (some methods were changed or deprecated therefore the showed above definition of the `SpaceKeyDownEventTrigger` is not compiled now). So, I put here the working version with custom `RoutedEvent` instead. The `SpaceKeyDownEvent` is defined in `MyControl` custom control and is raised from the `OnKeyDown` method when an unhandled `KeyDown` attached event reaches `MyControl` and the key pressed is the spacebar.

```c#
public class MyControl : ContentControl
{
    // This constructor is provided automatically if you
    // add a Custom Control (WPF) to your project
    static MyControl()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(
            typeof(MyControl),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyControl)));
    }

    // Create a custom routed event by first registering a RoutedEventID
    // This event uses the bubbling routing strategy
    public static readonly RoutedEvent SpaceKeyDownEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent(
        "SpaceKeyDown",
        RoutingStrategy.Bubble,
        typeof(RoutedEventHandler),
        typeof(MyControl));

    // Provide CLR accessors for the event
    public event RoutedEventHandler SpaceKeyDown
    {
        add { AddHandler(SpaceKeyDownEvent, value); }
        remove { RemoveHandler(SpaceKeyDownEvent, value); }
    }

    // This method raises the SpaceKeyDown event
    protected virtual void RaiseSpaceKeyDownEvent()
    {
        RoutedEventArgs args = new RoutedEventArgs(SpaceKeyDownEvent);
        RaiseEvent(args);
    }

    // Here KeyDown attached event is customized for the desired key
    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnKeyDown(e);

        if (e.Key == Key.Space)
            RaiseSpaceKeyDownEvent();
    }
}
```

The `MyControl` could be added to the template of another control, allowing the latter to use `EventTrigger` with the `SpaceKeyDown` routed event:

```xml
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyControl}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MyControl}">
                    <Grid>
                        <ContentPresenter/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <!-- Adding MyControl to the TextBox template -->
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                    <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <local:MyControl>
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="false" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"/>
                        </local:MyControl>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="local:MyControl.SpaceKeyDown">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground.Color"
                                                    From="White" To="Transparent" Duration="0:0:0.066" AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="3x"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```