# How to set focus on element on ItemsControl?

Tags: wpf

I've ItemsControl that its `ItemsSource` property bind to some dictionary from code behind. The `ItemTemplate` is consist of only one button. So, for each item in dictionary it creates button.

My question is how can I set focus to one of these buttons (dynamically)?
Should I use `ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem` ?
Any other idea?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, use can `ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem` to get a container for your data item, then you will need to find you button inside this container and call `Focus()` on the button.

OR you can use an attached property to bind IsFocused to a property on your data item. See [Set focus on textbox in WPF from view model (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356045/set-focus-on-textbox-in-wpf-from-view-model-c-wpf/1356781#1356781)