# MVVM DataGrid how to set focus after refresh content

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` like following:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding GridSource}" CanUserAddRows="False"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRow, Mode=TwoWay}">
...
</DataGrid>
```

I have a timer in `ViewModel` to refresh the content of `DataGrid`, after the content is updated, use `SelectedRow` to reset the current select row.

Check the UI result, the selected row works, but there is no blue background. I guess I miss set focus, but how to implement this?

Comment: I had solved my problem using SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex}" you need to pass value to SelectedIndex from model

Comment: You can take a look to my answer for similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42978210/7713750

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I guess I miss set focus, but how to implement this?

Programmatically focusing a row in a `DataGrid` and get the exact same behavior as when you select a row by clicking on it with the mouse requires some effort. Please refer to the following blog post for details.

[How to programmatically select and focus a row or cell in a DataGrid in WPF](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/11/08/how-to-programmatically-select-and-focus-a-row-or-cell-in-a-datagrid-in-wpf/)

```
private static void SelectRowByIndex(DataGrid dataGrid, int rowIndex)
{
    if (!dataGrid.SelectionUnit.Equals(DataGridSelectionUnit.FullRow))
        throw new ArgumentException(
        "The SelectionUnit of the DataGrid must be set to FullRow.");
    if (rowIndex < 0 || rowIndex > (dataGrid.Items.Count - 1))
        throw new ArgumentException(string.Format(
        "{0} is an invalid row index.", rowIndex));
    dataGrid.SelectedItems.Clear();
    /* set the SelectedItem property */
    object item = dataGrid.Items[rowIndex]; // = Product X
    dataGrid.SelectedItem = item;
    DataGridRow row =
        dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(rowIndex)
        as DataGridRow;
    if (row == null)
    {
        /* bring the data item (Product object) into view
         * in case it has been virtualized away */
        dataGrid.ScrollIntoView(item);
        row = dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator
            .ContainerFromIndex(rowIndex) as DataGridRow;
    }
    if (row != null)
    {
        DataGridCell cell = GetCell(dataGrid, row, 0);
        if (cell != null)
            cell.Focus();
    }
}

private static DataGridCell GetCell(DataGrid dataGrid,
    DataGridRow rowContainer, int column)
{
    if (rowContainer != null)
    {
        DataGridCellsPresenter presenter =
            FindVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>(rowContainer);
        if (presenter == null)
        {
            /* if the row has been virtualized away, call its
             * ApplyTemplate() method 
             * to build its visual tree in order for the
             * DataGridCellsPresenter
             * and the DataGridCells to be created */
            rowContainer.ApplyTemplate();
            presenter =
                FindVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>(rowContainer);
        }
        if (presenter != null)
        {
            DataGridCell cell =
            presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(column)
            as DataGridCell;
            if (cell == null)
            {
                /* bring the column into view
                 * in case it has been virtualized away */
                dataGrid.ScrollIntoView(rowContainer,
                    dataGrid.Columns[column]);
                cell =
                    presenter.ItemContainerGenerator
                    .ContainerFromIndex(column) as DataGridCell;
            }
            return cell;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

private static T FindVisualChild<T>(DependencyObject obj)
    where T : DependencyObject
{
    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj); i++)
    {
        DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i);
        if (child != null && child is T)
            return (T)child;
        else
        {
            T childOfChild = FindVisualChild<T>(child);
            if (childOfChild != null)
                return childOfChild;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```