# Editabled ComboBox in DataGrid Foucs Not Work

Tags: wpf, combobox, datagrid

I have a ComboBox in DataGrid,ComboBox's property `IsEditable="True"`,Mouse one click ComboBox,ComboBox is Focus,I find it's TextBox in ComboBox is Focus,But the row which focused ComboBox in DataGrid is not Focus.
But TextBox in DataGrid is not have this Problem.

```
         <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="测试3" Width="*">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox x:Name="tb" Text="{Binding Dm2}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="测试4" Width="*">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox x:Name="cb" IsEditable="True" ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.DmList,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}" SelectedValue="{Binding Dm2}" SelectedValuePath="Dm" DisplayMemberPath="Dm" Text="{Binding Dm2}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

[image]

I puzzle this problem three days,I'can find the way to solve the problem.

Comment: This can be useful for you [Datagrid row selected but not highlighted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42978210/7713750)

Comment: And this one [selection of a TreeView item as context menu is called](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43118460/7713750)

Answer (score 0):

A lower answer，but it can solve the problem https://www.cnblogs.com/ZXdeveloper/p/9183568.html