# How to select text of a texbox in wpf MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have some control in a stackpanel.
When I right click on the panel it gives me a context menu and I can edit the text of these control.
Here I used TextBlock to display the data and TextBox to edit the data (When TextBox is visible TextBlock become collapsed and vice versa)
I want to select all the text of the TextBox and focus it when the TextBox is visible.

I tried using Interaction. But didn't work out :(
Is there any way to do this?
For example : When the TextBox is visible I can fire some command in my viewmodel and select all the text from my viewmodel.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding MachineResponseText}" Visibility="{Binding IsEditing, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter=true}"/>
<TextBox x:Name="MachineResponseTextBox" Text="{Binding MachineResponseText, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Visibility="{Binding IsEditing, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}">
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsVisible" Value="True">
                    <!--Is there any way to select all the text when this textbox is visible?-->
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: What you want is to "highlight" all of the text in a `TextBox`, so your `VM` should stay out of it. This sounds to me like a code behind solution as the `VM` doesn't really care if the text is selected or not. Unless I misunderstood you?

Comment: Yeah thats true. I don't have to use VM. But how can I highlight the text and focus keyboard on the text field?

Comment: The `TextBox` has a `SelectedText` Property which you could set on `gotFocus` `event`. But if this is just switching between edit mode why not manipulate `IsEnabled` property on `TextBox`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to automatically select all text on focus in WPF TextBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/660554/how-to-automatically-select-all-text-on-focus-in-wpf-textbox)

Answer (score 0):

This is not complete answer to your question, more of push into proper direction.

Add GotKeyboardFocus handler to your textbox and run textbox.SelectAll(), i.e.

XAML part:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button>B1</Button>
    <TextBox Text="Test123" GotKeyboardFocus="TextBox_GotKeyboardFocus"/>
    <TextBlock>123</TextBlock>
    <Button>B2</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

Code behind part:

```
private void TextBox_GotKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var textBox = (TextBox) sender;
    if (textBox.SelectionLength == 0)
    {
        textBox.SelectAll();
    }
}
```

You might need to handle keyboard focus as well by calling `TextBox.Focus()` upon switching to edit mode, or in more MVVM way as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6737843/how-to-set-focus-to-textbox-using-mvvm)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the MVVM design pattern, I would suggest do it this way.

1. First you have to create a Extension method as below.

   ```
   public static class IsSelectTextExtension
   {
   public static readonly DependencyProperty IsSelectTextProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsSelectText", typeof(bool), typeof(IsSelectTextExtension), new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnIsSelectTextPropertyChanged));

   public static bool GetIsSelectText(DependencyObject obj)
   {
       return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsSelectTextProperty);
   }

   public static void SetIsSelectText(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
   {
       obj.SetValue(IsSelectTextProperty, value);
   }

   private static void OnIsSelectTextPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   {
       var uie = (TextBox)d;
       if ((bool)e.NewValue)
       {
           uie.SelectAll();
       }
   }
   }
   ```

   2. Include the namespace to the view and in your view (.xaml file) bind bool property to the extension that we created above.

```html
<Window x:Class="POS.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfExample"
        xmlns:extension="clr-namespace:WpfExample.Extension"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox extension:IsSelectTextExtension.IsSelectText="{Binding IsSelectText}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

3. In the view model class, define IsSelectText property and change the value according to your requirement.

   ```
   public class MainWindowViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
   private bool _isSelectText;
   public bool IsSelectText
   {
       get
       {
           return this._isSelectText;
       }
       set
       {
           _isSelectText = value;
           OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsSelectText));
       }
   }

   public NewSaleViewModel()
   {
   }

   #region INotifyPropertyChanged Implimentations

   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

   protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
   {
       if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
           this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
   }

   #endregion
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is usually the preferred `TextBox` behavior. You can change this for *all* text boxes in `App.xaml.cs`:

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    // ...
    EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(TextBox),
        UIElement.GotFocusEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(OnTextBoxGotFocus));
}

private static void OnTextBoxGotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is TextBox textBox && !textBox.IsReadOnly)
    {
        textBox.SelectAll();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There's an event that you can use and it's appliend in all `UIElement` 
[UIElement.IsVisibleChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.isvisiblechanged.aspx)
After that you have to make the focus in the textbox and select the text like this

```
private void TextBox_IsVisibleChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    this.myTextBox.Focus();
    this.myTextBox.SelectAll();
}
```

this is a code behind version you can do the same in a mvvm context by firing the event in your view model.

this stackoverflow post might help you if you want to set a textbox focus in mvvm.

[How to set focus to textbox using MVVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6737843/how-to-set-focus-to-textbox-using-mvvm?noredirect=1&lq=1)