# Focus on textBox on the page load with MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I can't set keyboard focus on textbox control when my UI form loads. I am using MVVM pattern and when I tried solution on the following link but this didn't help. When the form loads there is a caret in my textbox but it's not flashing, and I can't write text in it. The same thing happens when I use FocusManager.focused element in XAML. I also tried with Keyboard.Focus(MytextBox) but the same thing happened... Please help anybody, I am stuck 2 days with this...

This is class where i made dependency property IsFocused and used it for binding with isFocused property in my viewmodel:

```
public  static class Attached
{

public static DependencyProperty IsFocusedProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsFocused", typeof(bool), typeof(Attached), new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnIsFocusedChanged));

public static bool GetIsFocused(DependencyObject dependencyObject)
{
    return (bool)dependencyObject.GetValue(IsFocusedProperty);
}

public static void SetIsFocused(DependencyObject dependencyObject, bool value)
{
    dependencyObject.SetValue(IsFocusedProperty, value);
}

public static void OnIsFocusedChanged(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
{
    TextBox textBox = dependencyObject as TextBox;
    bool newValue = (bool)dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs.NewValue;
    bool oldValue = (bool)dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs.OldValue;
    Keyboard.Focus(textBox);
    if (newValue && !oldValue && !textBox.IsFocused)  textBox.Focus();
}

}
```

This is my XAML:

```
<TextBox a:Attached.IsFocused="{Binding IsFocused, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}.../>"
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set focus on a textbox control in UserControl in wpf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19225443/set-focus-on-a-textbox-control-in-usercontrol-in-wpf)

Comment: Its probably because it's trying to set focus at render time, before the control is loaded, and you can't set focus then. Try using the `Dispatcher` to set the focus at a later `DispatcherPriority`, such as `DispatcherPriority.Loaded`, and I think it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this u can use your code behind file. In the page loaded event you should do

```
MyTextBox.Focus();
```

Comment: Since this is UI related only, this approach does not break MVVM pattern. I do the same in my code.

Answer (score 2):

In the `Window`-Element you can write

```
FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=textBox}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You maybe get a problem with the loaded-timing, meaning you set focus but it gets stolen afterwards. You can try to defer that by using a dispatcher:

```
myView.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
{
   textBox.Focus();
}), DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor of code behind the file write code where my `textbox` name is `txtUsername`:

> ```
>   public LoginView()
>   {
>       InitializeComponent();
>       txtUsername.Focus();
>   }
> ```