# How to autofocus textbox on TrayPopup in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am working on an application with `TaskbarIcon` from [hardcodet](http://www.hardcodet.net/). When I activate my `CustomTrayPopup`, I would like to have my `CustomTextBox` to be focused. The normal way within xaml doesn't seem to work.

Here's my code:

```
<UserControl [...]>
    <Grid x:Name="Grid">
        <Border [...]>
            [...]
        </Border>
        <TextBox [...]
                 FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                 > [...]
                <TextBox.Template>
                    [...]
                </TextBox.Template>
            </TextBox>
        <ListBox [...]>[...]
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Is there some way to make the `TextBox` autofocus when calling the `TrayPopup`? Doesn't matter if xaml or code behind.

UPDATE 1:
My `CustomTextBox` consists of an `Button` and the `TextField`. Here's whats inside of my `TextBox.Template`

```
<ControlTemplate>
  <Border [...]>
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>[...]
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <DockPanel>
      <Button [...]>
        <Image [...]/>
        <Button.Style>[...]
        </Button.Style>
      </Button>
      <ScrollViewer Margin="0"
                    x:Name="PART_ContentHost"/>
    </DockPanel>
  </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Is it possible, that `FocusManager` can not handle the button inside my `TextBox`?

UPDATE 2:
I added a `OnClick` method for my `Button` inside the `CustomTextBox`, where all the Text is selected and the `PART_ContentHost` gets focused. But it doesn't work when i try inside the `OnLoaded` method oder others alike.

UPDATE 3:
Here is the complete Template for my TextBox, in case it matters.

```
<TextBox KeyDown="SearchBox_KeyDown"
                 x:Name="SearchBox"
                 Width="160" 
                 Height="20" 
                 Margin="10,10,150,130"
                 SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                 OverridesDefaultStyle="True"
                 Foreground="#FFFFFFFF"
                 Text="Some"
                 >

                <TextBox.CaretBrush>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF997137"/>
                </TextBox.CaretBrush>
                <TextBox.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Border x:Name="Border"
                            Margin="1"
                            CornerRadius="2"
                            BorderThickness="0,0,0,1.5"
                            BorderBrush="#FF997137">
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                                                      Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                 Value="#FF8f8f8f"/>
                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="ReadOnly">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                                                      Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                 Value="#FF4b4b4b"/>
                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <DockPanel>
                                <Button BorderThickness="0" 
                                        DockPanel.Dock="Left" 
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                                        Height="15" 
                                        Width="15"
                                        Background="#00ffffff"
                                        Click="Button_Click">
                                <Image Source="/Resources/searchIco.png"
                                       Margin="2"
                                       Stretch="Fill"/>
                                <Button.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                        <Setter Property="Template">
                                            <Setter.Value>
                                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                                    </Border>
                                                </ControlTemplate>
                                            </Setter.Value>
                                        </Setter>
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#00ffffff"/>
                                            </Trigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                </Button.Style>
                            </Button>
                                <ScrollViewer Margin="0"
                                              x:Name="PART_ContentHost"/>
                            </DockPanel>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </TextBox.Template>
            </TextBox>
```

Comment: have you tried to subscribe on IsVisibleChanged event, and set focus by calling FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(...) ?

Comment: I tried that now, but it does not help.

Comment: did you check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19225443/set-focus-on-a-textbox-control-in-usercontrol-in-wpf ??

Comment: @Akansha: I tried these Answers now, but it didn't help either.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IsVisibleChanged` event to set focus on your `TextBox`. This sets the focus not only when the View or Usercontrol loads, but also if you a changing Views by way of Visibility. If you try to set it through the Loaded event, the event may not fire in case of hide and show. So changing the Focus of the control on VisibilityChange is helpful as it will always fire.

Here is an example to set Focus on the textbox through code behind in the UserControl

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.IsVisibleChanged += UserControl1_IsVisibleChanged;
        }

        void UserControl1_IsVisibleChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {         
           txt.Focus();
         //txt is the name of the TextBox which is to be focused
        }
    }
```

Comment: I already tried that without success. I have some similar ButtonClick event that will work. But I don't know why.

Comment: But this worked for me.. Let me check with the Template

Comment: I tried with your template also. But it worked for me.. :(

Comment: I don't know either. As I said, it works with clicking the button, but not with any other event.

Comment: Jup. The Event is raising, but nothing happens

Comment: Add some text to your textbox in Xaml and check whether it is displayed or not.

Comment: i did. It is displayed.

Comment: Make a sample application with only TextBox and its Template. It is only then you can know where the problem is exactly. Even I am unable to know the issue. May be the other controls are creating some impact. The sample may help you.

Comment: ok I tried a sample application. and it's working fine... thats making me crazy. It seems that the TextBox is losing Focus after running the method. but not when Clicking the button.

Comment: Method doesn't matter. Can be *_Loaded or *_VisibilityChanged. I also tried setting the Text and SelectAll(). Everythings working, but The TextBox loses Focus because of some reason