# trigger on texbox got focus

Tags: xaml, mvvm, triggers, textbox, visibility

I have virtual keyboard which should be hidden and i want to show it only when textbox get focus. I'm using mvvm so i dont want to write any code on code behind, so i want to make some trigger if it's possible which can watch all texboxes and set visibility on my virtual keyboard.
Or i can do it in controller but i cant find the way how to get current focused control

```
<DockPanel FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding FocusedElement, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately didn't found solution to use triggers but atleast i can get IsFocused value using extension, got it from here [Set focus on textbox in WPF from view model (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356045/set-focus-on-textbox-in-wpf-from-view-model-c-wpf)