# Update Viewmodel prop when the user control lost focus

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, focus

```
<UserControl  UIHelper:FocusExtension.IsFocused="{Binding FocusUserControl,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Focusable="True" IsTabStop="True">
```

here I added an IsFocused prop to maintain the focus of usercontrol

```
 public static class FocusExtension
    {
        public static bool GetIsFocused(DependencyObject obj)
        {

            return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsFocusedProperty);

        }

        public static void SetIsFocused(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(IsFocusedProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsFocusedProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
                "IsFocused", typeof(bool), typeof(FocusExtension),
                new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnIsFocusedPropertyChanged));

        private static void OnIsFocusedPropertyChanged(
            DependencyObject d,
            DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var uie = (UIElement)d;
            if ((bool)e.NewValue)
            {
                 uie.Focus();
            }
        }
    }
```

this is my FocusExtension class

```
public bool FocusUserControl
        {
            get { return focusUserControl; }
            set
            {
                focusUserControl = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("FocusUserControl"));
            }
        }
```

this is my VM prop. which is binded, now in user control, I have a button. when I click on it a **new user control** will. open at that time **I need to update the `FocusUserControl` to false. as** **the focus is not on that usercontrol** anymore. I am stuck here please suggest something thanks for ur help.

**

> Update i added something like  this

**

```
 private static void OnIsFocusedPropertyChanged(
            DependencyObject d,
            DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            uie = (UIElement)d;
            if ((bool)e.NewValue)
            {
                uie.LostKeyboardFocus += LostFocus;
                uie.Focus();
            }

        }
        static void LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            uie.LostKeyboardFocus -= LostFocus;
            // Here i need to update `FocusUserControl` to false 
        }
```

in LostFocus i just need to update `FocusUserControl` to false. how can i do it? really use some help.

Comment: please add some punctuation to your question it is hard to read specifically dots colons dashes and question marks are super useful thanks also your dp is not subscribing to any control event looks like it is working only one way

Comment: I think I want to subscribe to `LostFocus` not sure. is that right? and yes it is working in one way from VM to ui  @vasily.sib

Comment: Attached property is not the best solution for this. What you actualy want is to trigger some action on view's event. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14122823/how-to-trigger-viewmodel-command-for-a-specific-button-events) question and specifically at acepted answer - it is not about `LostFocus` event but can be modified easily.

Comment: @vasily.sib As my application is based on warehouse I think I can't use it he is my exact problem, in user control, I have a button which will open another user control and they will perform some operations. once they close it they will use the scanner to give input as my user control is not focused on current user control its not takeing input

Comment: @vasily.sib if user clicks on current usercontrol and start scanning it will work fine as the focus changed so there wont be mouse clicks i need to focus it through code

Comment: @vasily.sib please check the update once can update the prop

Comment: if anyone looking for ans [this is the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16966029/7765929)

Comment: If there are multiple controls in the usercontrol use IsKeyboardFocusWithinChanged.