# Set keyboard focus on textbox on startup using mvvm

Tags: mvvm

I can't set keyboard focus on textbox control when my UI form loads. I am using MVVM pattern and when I 
tried solution on the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19657951/how-to-set-focus-to-a-wpf-control-using-mvvm) but this didn't help. When the form loads there is a caret 
in my textbox but it's not flashing, and I can't write text in it. The same thing happens when I use
FocusManager.focused element in XAML. I also tried with Keyboard.Focus(MytextBox) but the same thing happened... Please help anybody, I am stuck 2 days with this...

This is class where i made dependency property IsFocused and used it for binding with isFocused property in my viewmodel:

```
public  static class Attached
{

    public static DependencyProperty IsFocusedProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsFocused", typeof(bool), typeof(Attached), new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnIsFocusedChanged));

    public static bool GetIsFocused(DependencyObject dependencyObject)
    {
        return (bool)dependencyObject.GetValue(IsFocusedProperty);
    }

    public static void SetIsFocused(DependencyObject dependencyObject, bool value)
    {
        dependencyObject.SetValue(IsFocusedProperty, value);
    }

    public static void OnIsFocusedChanged(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
    {
        TextBox textBox = dependencyObject as TextBox;
        bool newValue = (bool)dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs.NewValue;
        bool oldValue = (bool)dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs.OldValue;
        Keyboard.Focus(textBox);
        if (newValue && !oldValue && !textBox.IsFocused)  textBox.Focus();
    }

}
```

This is my XAML:

```
  <TextBox a:Attached.IsFocused="{Binding IsFocused, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}.../>"
```

Comment: What language are you using? And can you show us some code?

Comment: So now can we see some code?