# WPF setting focus back to textbox on modal Window close

Tags: wpf

Assume there is a WPF window with multiple textboxes and one button. Currently the cursor is blinking in one of the textBox and then on button click I launched a modal window and then on close of this Window I want the Cursor blinking back to the textbox where it was before launch of the modal window. 
How I can achieve it in WPF?

```
FocusManager.GetFocusedElement
```

It will give the button, not the textbox.

Comment: are you using MVVM pattern?

Comment: you can have a look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19657951/how-to-set-focus-to-a-wpf-control-using-mvvm