# Setting focus on a textbox on change of dropdown value

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I've a xaml screen in my  C#/WPF app having a combobox(ProductType) and a textbox(ProductCode).
When the screen loads for the first time,I'm setting the focus this Textbox and its working fine using my code below.
I also need to set the focus when user changes a value in the comboxbox but it does not seem to work.

What am I missing here please?
(Note:My first preference would be to achieve a solution for this using MVVM design pattern.If it does not work,I would like to go for code-behind approach please.)

**MainWindowResources.xaml**

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="ProductCodeStyle">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding FocusOnProductCode}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

**MainWindow.xaml:**

```
<TextBox  Name="txtProductCode" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="22" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding ProductCodeValue, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged }"   
                      VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="165" Style="{DynamicResource ProductCodeStyle}" Grid.Column="3" Margin="1,2,0,0" TabIndex="0" IsHitTestVisible="True"/>
```

**MainWindowViewModel.cs**

```
public MainWindowViewModel(MainWindow window)
{

this.FocusOnProductCode = true;
}


 public ProductType SelectedProductType
        {
            get
            {
                return m_selectedProductType;
            }
            set
            {                
                m_selectedProductType = value;

                this.FocusOnProductCode = true;

            }
        }



        public bool FocusOnProductCode
        {
            get { return m_focusOnProductCode; }
            set
            {
                m_focusOnProductCode;= value;
                OnPropertyChanged("FocusOnProductCode");
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedProductType");
            }
        }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Setting focus is a concern of the UI.  Just watch the combo box in the codebehind of the window and set your focus as appropriate.

Comment: Thanks @Will.But I would like to see if there's any solution for this using MVVM design pattern.Have updated my question with the same.

Comment: Doing your UI work in the codebehind *is* using the MVVM design pattern.  Shoehorning UI work into your ViewModel is the exact *opposite* of the MVVM design pattern.  Don't feel bad--rejoice!  You can solve this problem in only a few moments and lines of code!  And you would be adhering to the pattern!  It's a win-win!

Answer (score 0):

Focusing an element in pure XAML by setting the FocusManager.FocusedElement attached property in a Style setter dynamically at runtime won't work but you could use a behaviour to be able to set a Boolean property indicating whether the element should be focused in the view model class as suggested in the following threads:

[Set focus on textbox in WPF from view model (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356045/set-focus-on-textbox-in-wpf-from-view-model-c)

[How to set Focus to a WPF Control using MVVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19657951/how-to-set-focus-to-a-wpf-control-using-mvvm)

```
<TextBox  Name="txtProductCode" Text="{Binding ProductCodeValue, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" local:FocusExtension.IsFocused="{Binding FocusOnProductCode}"/>
```