# wpf setting keyboard focus on textbox using xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml

in a wpf project afer the window loads i am trying to set focus on a textbox using the xaml.

My textbox is inside a grid.Here is the code i used

```
<Grid Name="gvLoginPage"
      Margin="0,30,0,0"
      FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=txtUserName}">
 <TextBox Name="txtUserName"
          Focusable="True"
          ToolTip="Please enter your user name"
          Width="300"
          Height="22"
          VerticalContentAlignment="Top"
          TextWrapping="Wrap"
          Grid.Row="0"
          Grid.Column="1"
          BorderBrush="Black">
<Grid>
```

this code is setting the focus but cursor is not blinking and i can not type anything.

Then i came across this question [Get and restore WPF keyboard focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19289994/get-and-restore-wpf-keyboard-focus) where he explains that there are two types of focus one is logical focus and other is keyboard focus and FocusManager.FocusedElement sets logical focus not keyboard focus.so i can not get blinking cursor.

using code behind i can solve this using

```
Keyboard.Focus(txtUserName);
```

But i want to keep my code behind as less as possible.so please somebody help me to set keyboard focus on textbox using xaml.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19225443/set-focus-on-a-textbox-control-in-usercontrol-in-wpf

Comment: I have already checked this link.but i want to know is there a way to do it using only xaml.otherwise i can use Keyboard.Focus method also.

Comment: Using only xaml to set focus is already mentioned in the same link. Please check all the answers.

Comment: The link above shows a method of achieving this without breaking the MVVM pattern. If you want a pure XAML approach, you could adapt that example to use an event trigger that fires on the window `Loaded` event.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to @olitee's comment i used my gridview's IsVisible property to fire a DataTrigger and set the Focusmanager.FocusedElement to my Textbox.here is the code

```
<Style x:Key="trgFocus" TargetType="TextBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=gvLoginPage, Path=IsVisible}" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement" Value="{Binding ElementName=txtUserName}" />
                </DataTrigger>

            </Style.Triggers>
```

Now i am getting blinking cursor.Thanks @olitee and @Palak