# Set Focus to Checkbox in ComboBox in order to get keyboard control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, checkbox, combobox

I have a `ComboBox` which has `CheckBox`es as items:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding SomeCollectionProperty}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding SomeBoolProperty}" Width="20" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Width="140" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

If the `ComboBox` gets keyboard focus, I can select an item with the up and down arrow keys. I can then switch focus to the `CheckBox` with <kbd>tab</kbd> and am able to switch the `CheckBox`'s `IsChecked` state by pressing <kbd>space</kbd>.
I'm looking for a solution that allows me to do the same but without manually switching focus to the `CheckBox`. My desired behavior would be:

1. Choose item with arrow keys
2. Choose state with <kbd>space</kbd>

I tried to do it with `EventTrigger` and `InputBinding` and by fiddling around with the `Focusable` property but with no luck.
I would prefer a solution in `xaml` but a code-behind solution would still be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19289994/get-and-restore-wpf-keyboard-focus) (answer provided by [Sheridan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/249281/sheridan))

the idea is to set `CheckBox` as `FocusManager.FocusedElement`

the difference here is that CheckBox is a part of `DataTemplate` and it is necessary to check `IsFocused` property of ComboBox

```
<CheckBox.Style>
    <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsFocused, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ComboBox}}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</CheckBox.Style>
```

Comment: It works but I'm not quite sure why. From just looking at it, it appears as if every `CeckBox` will try to get focus whenever the `ComboBox` is focused. However only the selected one will actually get the focus. Is this because all the other `CheckBox`es are `Collapsed` and therefore cannot draw focus?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following:

```
<ComboBoxItem GotFocus="ComboBoxItem_GotFocus">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <CheckBox Name="test" Width="20" Height="20" />
            <TextBlock  Width="140" />
        </StackPanel>
</ComboBoxItem>
```

The C#:

```
private void ComboBoxItem_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    test.Focus();
}
```

This worked for me.
Now I understand that this probably won't work in your situation because If I see it right, you're trying to use an MVVM pattern. What you can do though, is using a `RelayCommand` (good tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6EOdTEI6ERI)) in your `ViewModel` that gets triggered when you get focus. Then when you get focus, you can set the new focus on your checkbox from your `ViewModel`. Correct me if I'm wrong since I'm pretty new to WPF, but hope that helps!

Comment: I don't have a specific `ComboBoxItem` because I'm using a `DataTemplate`.

Comment: Yeah I already said that the example probably won't work, but it might give you an idea of how to solve it using MVVM and databinding. If you have a ViewModel with these two items then you can bind the gotfocus command to your ViewModel and play around with it