# Set focus to WF combobox in WPF application

Tags: wpf, winforms, combobox, textbox

I am using a `WindowsFormsHost` to host a WF `ComboBox` in my WPF application

I'd like to set the `focus` of the keyboard to be inside of the `ComboBox`'s `TextBox` via my C# code

I've tried things like `myComboBox.focus()` but haven't had any luck

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Peek into this question:
[Get and restore WPF keyboard focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19289994/get-and-restore-wpf-keyboard-focus)

TLDR: Consider using `Keyboard.Focus(System.Windows.IInputElement element)` method.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/focus-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) is another article to read.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that ComboBox is not of type IInputElement, so I can't use Keyboard.Focus