# how to apply a style using a converter in wpf c#?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, telerik

I am developing a system with voice commands that apply to a grid of parameters.
I want to apply a style to the element being edited, so that the user knows where he is vocally ...

MyView.xaml

```
 <telerik:RadNumericUpDown Name={Binding Element[0].ID}  Grid.Column="0" Name="Left" MinWidth="15" FontSize="11" Minimum="0" NumberDecimalDigits="0" 
BorderThickness="0" Maximum="30" 
IsInteger="True" ShowButtons="False" ShowTextBox="True" 
HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"  Value="{Binding Element[0].Input, Mode=TwoWay, ElementName=InputViewUserControl}" Background="Transparent" Foreground="#FF858585"  />


 <telerik:RadNumericUpDown Name={Binding Element[1].ID}  Grid.Column="0" Name="Left" MinWidth="15" FontSize="11" Minimum="0" NumberDecimalDigits="0" 
BorderThickness="0" Maximum="30" 
IsInteger="True" ShowButtons="False" ShowTextBox="True" 
HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"  Value="{Binding Element[1].Input, Mode=TwoWay, ElementName=InputViewUserControl}" Background="Transparent" Foreground="#FF858585"  />

 <telerik:RadNumericUpDown Name={Binding Element[2].ID}  Grid.Column="0" Name="Left" MinWidth="15" FontSize="11" Minimum="0" NumberDecimalDigits="0" 
BorderThickness="0" Maximum="30" 
IsInteger="True" ShowButtons="False" ShowTextBox="True" 
HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"  Value="{Binding Element[2].Input, Mode=TwoWay, ElementName=InputViewUserControl}" Background="Transparent" Foreground="#FF858585"  />
```

.....i have 30 elements So...

If the user says: element one, I'd like to apply style to Element[0]

If you have an idea let me know Thanks :)

Comment: Consider changing style in LostFocus, GotFocus and setting focus based on your voice processing function.

Comment: `....i have 30 elements So...` - Please remove all that horrible repetition immediately and use an `ItemsControl`.

Comment: @Allel The question is how to know what is the voice, or after you know what the voice was, how to change the style?

Comment: :)  this is solution of my problem 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356045/set-focus-on-textbox-in-wpf-from-view-model-c-wpf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need one `Style` in a `Resources` section and then you need to add one `bool IsSelected` property to your `Element` class:

```
public bool IsSelected { get; set; } // Implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface here

<Style TargetType="{x:Type telerik:RadNumericUpDown}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

The `Style` will colour the `Background` of the object that has an `IsSelected` property that is set to `True`. All you need to do now is to set the `IsSelected` property to `True` for the current object and set the previous object's `IsSelected` value to `False`.

Note that this `Style` has no `x:Key` value... that means that it will be implicitly set on all of your controls without you needing to set the `Style` on each element manually.