# FocusManager.FocusedElement and MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, focus

I'd like to control which button is focused in my view. User must be able to perform a job without need to use mouse. And job is going through all elements. Depending on element, some buttons will appears, some disappears.

I could do it with dependency properties. To example, if there are buttons <kbd>Previous</kbd> and <kbd>Next</kbd>, then I can provide `IsPreviousFocused` and `IsNextFocused` to set focus to them after certain event. Events can be: showing window for the first time (something should have focus already), reaching 1 element (hiding <kbd>Previous</kbd> button, setting `IsNextFocused`), reaching last element (opposite), etc.

This looks reasonable more or less.

But, if I have, to example, 10 buttons (different operations), then all of them will have to have dependency property!

So I was thinking about much easier approach: when I hide button, there will be **no**  focus

```
if(FocusManager.FocusedElement == null) { ... }
```

If I can detect, when there are no focus, then I can try to set it to one of the buttons somehow. This way, I don't really need any complicated *focus management*

Question is: how to deal with `FocusManager.FocusedElement` in MVVM scenario? How to detect when there is no focus (when window is shown first time, when certain button is clicked and become invisible, etc)?

P.S.: I actually hate ms for making another technology without thinking fully into it; focus is very basic feature (and everybody **care** about it in their software), but there is no direct support for it (in xaml); looks like *"oh, its too complicated, lets skip it"* solution.

Comment: why not use keybindings or ALT+ _key? for your buttons?

Comment: @blindmeis, I myself do not like keybindings. Take to example some *multi-page wizard* (nsis installer), you can press `Enter` key all the way through it to get some result. Wizard itself can be started by keybinding, but operations inside are most of time `Next` (assuming default values are ok for you). This is something what I want to have. User will click `Next` most of times, but sometime he can click `Previous` or chose some option, this is where I need to manage focus (reaching 1 element, last element, first start, etc).

Answer (score 1):

You could control your focus from your ViewModel by using the approach shown here:
[Set focus on textbox in WPF from view model (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356045/set-focus-on-textbox-in-wpf-from-view-model-c-wpf)

Comment: Was there already (and more likely in every *related* and *sub-related* topic). This is a scenario, where I have to define variable for **each** button individually. I am looking for something more generic, more elegant, *lesscody*. Ability to detect when there is no focus at all, to set it on something.

Comment: You can instead define a single string/enum variable in your ViewModel, which 'names' the focussed element. 
Then for each Button, you can bind the AttachedProperty to this variable using a ValueConverter with a ConverterParameter => each Button uses a different ConverterParameter. The ValueConverter should return true if the ConverterParameter is equal to the value (the ViewModel-variable).