# Should a ViewModel control focus in the View

Tags: wpf, mvvm-light

I have an ItemsControl binding to a collection in the ViewModel. As a result of user input, a new item gets added to the collection and this gets displayed on the View.

The item is also a View-ViewModel pair, the View contains a TextBox that I would like to receive focus **immediately** after being added to the collection.

How do I set the focus to a TextBox without referencing the View from within the ViewModel? Are attached properties the way to go here?

Answer (score 1):

well you can do this by creating a behaviour..

have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356045/set-focus-on-textbox-in-wpf-from-view-model-c) to get an idea of behaviours controlling focus