# Create a WPF user control that it's focus behaves as a native control

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, controls

I had made a user control that is a replacement for the combo box, it has search and LINQ queries capabilities.

The control is made by composition, it has a TextBox where the user type, a TextBlock that serves as the auto-complete label, a ListBox inside a Popup for the drop down and the drop down button.

The problem is that each of this controls has its own focus, and when a consumer of this user control calls the SetFocus() for the user control, the focus is not setted to the TextBox, even if I subscribe to the GotFocus event, this is because the user control itself is not focusable.

If instead I set the **IsFocusable = True** and **KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop = True** the user control itself can be focused, but the text box its not focused, instead, a dotted line appears around the control

I need that the user control behave the same way as the native ComboBox, when a consumer calls the SetFocus() the inner TextBox should be focusd

I could expose a custom method for focusing the inner TextBox, but this is not an option because I have an attached property (from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356045/set-focus-on-textbox-in-wpf-from-view-model-c) question) that allows me to set the focus of any control from the ViewModel, thus the focus behaviour should be the same for all controls

Comment: There are multiple problems with your approach: 1 - a `UserControl` is not intended for what you did here, a *custom control* is. Start reading [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms745025(v=vs.100).aspx). 2 - anything related to LINQ is a data concern and is not a responsibility of the View. Should be done by a proper ViewModel instead. 3 - you should have derived from `Selector` if you're going to select items.

Comment: Also, since you derived from `UserControl`, which in turn is a `ContentControl`, what happens if I do `<your:ComboBox><SomeElement/></your:ComboBox>` and put `SomeElement` inside of your UserControl in XAML? it's either not going to work, or blow up.

Comment: For reference, I created my own LookupBox with similar capabilities, and it consists of a (code-only, no XAML) class derived from `Selector`, and a default (generic.xaml) template for that.

Comment: Thanks, I will read about custom controls, it is the correct approach. @HighCore Why anything related to LINQ is data concern? If a control already depends on IEnumerable, can't depend also on IQueryable<T> ? This is because i want that, if the ItemsSource supports it, that the search is done via the LINQ Where statement, instead of a foreach or IEnumerable Where search