# How to show floating virtual keyboard (user control) in MainWindow when an input control (from another user control) has been set to focus in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have been doing development work in WPF application which uses an MVVM pattern for a couple of days now.  I'm very new to WPF and MVVM pattern as well.

In my scenario, I have a user control view (named EPayView.xaml) which has a textbox that will accept a phone number.  The view has a corresponding viewmodel (named EPayViewModel.cs).  In the MainWindow.xaml, I have a user control (floating virtual keyboard) which is derived from namespace controls WpfKb.Controls.  The MainWindow.xaml also has a corresponding viewmodel (named MainViewModel.cs)

Having said that, I have done research on how to use attached dependency properties which lead me to this solution. [Set focus on textbox in WPF from view model (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356045/set-focus-on-textbox-in-wpf-from-view-model-c) which I believe this is where I could bind the property IsFocused in the textbox of EPayView.xaml.

Below are the codes that I have already incorporated in my solution.

**EpayView.xaml** (textbox xaml markup)

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding PhoneNo}" Grid.Row="5" Margin="10,0,10,0" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="12" x:Name="Email" behaviors:FocusExtension.IsFocused="{Binding IsFocused, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

**MainWindow.xaml** (xaml markup)

```
<Window x:Class="SmartPole540.View.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:WpfKb.Controls;assembly=SmartPole.WpfKb"
    xmlns:wpf="clr-namespace:WebEye.Controls.Wpf;assembly=WebEye.Controls.Wpf.WebCameraControl"
    xmlns:utilities="clr-namespace:SoltaLabs.Avalon.Core.Utilities;assembly=SoltaLabs.Avalon.Core"
    xmlns:userControls="clr-namespace:SoltaLabs.Avalon.View.Core.UserControls;assembly=SoltaLabs.Avalon.View.Core"
    xmlns:square="clr-namespace:SmartPole.View.Square;assembly=SmartPole.View"
    xmlns:view="clr-namespace:SmartPole.View;assembly=SmartPole.View"
    Title="CitiPulse" 
    WindowStartupLocation="Manual"
    PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="Window_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"
    Name="mainWindow">

    <userControls:RollPanel.BottomContent>
        <square:SquareView Canvas.Top="1010" DataContext="{Binding DataContext.SquareViewModel, 
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type userControls:RollPanel}}}"/>
    </userControls:RollPanel.BottomContent>

    <controls:FloatingTouchScreenKeyboard
            x:Name="floatKb" Width="500" Height="250" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=MainGrid}"
            Placement="Center" AreAnimationsEnabled="False" Visibility="Visible"
            IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=kbButton}"/>
</Window>
```

In the above code, the user control RollPanel.BottomContent host the EPayView.xaml view inside another view which is RollPanel.xaml

**EpayViewModel.cs** contains the static class FocusExtension for the IsFocused attached property (refer to this solution - [Set focus on textbox in WPF from view model (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356045/set-focus-on-textbox-in-wpf-from-view-model-c)). And, EPayViewModel.cs already implemented INotifyPropertyChanged which is wrapped inside a concrete class ObservableObject that accepts type of T.  This is also same with MainViewModel.cs

```
public class EPayViewModel : ObservableObject<EPayViewModel>, IPaymentViewModel, IActiveViewModel
{ ... }

public class MainViewModel : ObservableObject<MainViewModel>
{ ... }
```

As such, my goal is that when the textbox in EPayView.xaml has the focus, the floating virtual keyboard (floatKb) in the MainWindow.xaml will be shown.

I'm stuck on how to proceed (I was thinking if a call to FocusExtension static class in EPayViewModel inside my **MainViewModel.cs** will suffice?), any help is greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

Comment: Use `Command` which is the way to go.

Comment: @AnjumSKhan, how do I use the Command? I'm pretty new to MVVM.  Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As *AnjumSKhan* already said, to react to some event in a MVVM way, you'll have to use `Command`. Command can be called within an `EventTrigger`, you will need to add a Reference to `System.Windows.Interactvity` component.
Let's assume you have a simple View and View Model and you need to show this View when the TextBox in a MainWindow got focus.

**View (NewWindow.xaml)**

```
<Window x:Class="My.NewWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="NewWindow" Height="300" Width="300">
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Message}"/>
```

**View Model**

```
public class NewWindowViewModel
{
    private string _message;
    public string Message
    {
        get { return _message; }
        set { _message = value; }
    }
}
```

You also have a MainWindow, it is a main view for an app and it contains the target `TextBox`. You may see that there is an EventTrigger added to the TextBox and it has a property `InvokeCommandAction` which is binded to the `MainWindowViewModel`'s command called `ShowCommand`.

**Main Window**

```
<Window x:Class="My.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:Interactivity="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity" Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<TextBox Height="40" Text="{Binding Text}">
    <Interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
        <Interactivity:EventTrigger EventName="GotFocus">
            <Interactivity:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ShowCommand}"/>
        </Interactivity:EventTrigger>
    </Interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
</TextBox>
```

In the `Show` method of MainWindowViewModel `NewWindow` view is created and got new `NewWindowViewModel` instance as a `DataContext`. RelayCommand class is presented in [my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41285758/692829)

**MainWindowViewModel**

```
public class MainWindowViewModel
{
    private string _text;
    public string Text
    {
        get { return _text; }
        set { _text = value; }
    }

    private ICommand _increaseCommand;
    public ICommand ShowCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_increaseCommand == null)
            {
                _increaseCommand = new RelayCommand(
                p => true,
                Show);
            }
            return _increaseCommand;
        }
    }

    private void Show(object obj)
    {
        var w = new NewWindow();
        var nvm = new NewWindowViewModel();
        nvm.Message = "Test";
        w.DataContext = nvm;
        w.Show();
    }
}
```

What is left is to create a new MainWindowViewModel and setup a DataContext for MainWindow.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var mvm = new MainWindowViewModel();
    mvm.Text = "Focus me!";
    DataContext = mvm;
}
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I haven't tried your solution yet.  But, I do appreciate it.  This is really a good head start to understand on how to use Command.