# Set Default Value for ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

In my solution I have set the default value for list like below code

```
<ListBox x:Name="SelectorList" 
         ItemsSource="{Binding ViewStatusList}"
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDeviceItem,Mode=TwoWay}"        
         IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
```

create the property for SelectedDeviceItem in my view model.

```
private Device _selecteddeviceitem;
public Device SelectedDeviceItem
{
    get
    {
        return _selecteddeviceitem;
    }
    set
    {
        _selecteddeviceitem = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedDeviceItem");
    }
}
```

and passed `SelectedDeviceItem = StatusList[0];`
in the constructor.
But still my listbox will be shown like below.

[image]

But I need the result should be like below image

[image]

What have I missed in the this list box code?

Comment: Are you sure the difference between the two images is not because one of them has focus and the other one does not? In this case use the solution presented [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356045/set-focus-on-textbox-in-wpf-from-view-model-c)

Comment: Listbox selectedIndex="0" it set first item selected . I think you need to set focus for the selected item .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this could achieve it:

1. Set the selected `ListBoxItem` to be focused.

   ```
   private void ListBox_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
   {

       var listbox = sender as ListBox;
       var listboxItem =
           listbox?.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(listbox.SelectedItem) as ListBoxItem;
       listboxItem?.Focus(); 
   }
   ```
2. Set focus when the `ListBox` loaded. This is because that the `ListBoxItems` may be selected before they are generated.

   ```
   private void ListBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       var listbox = sender as ListBox;
       var listboxItem =
           listbox?.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(listbox.SelectedItem) as ListBoxItem;
       listboxItem?.Focus();
   }
   ```

Note that the logic of making item being selected should not be achieved in the view model, it's just kind of a UI logic.

Answer (score -1):

it seems ListboxItem not focused . Please Set ListBox to focus and item to focus

```
listBox.Focus();
var listBoxItem = (ListBoxItem)listBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(listBox.SelectedItem);
listBoxItem.Focus();
```

Comment: Setting the focus in MVVM is more difficult.

Comment: Not MVVM per-se, but where should this code be placed to achieve the desired results? It does not give that answer.