# WPF auto click button of first result DataGrid after pressing ENTER on research textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm working on a WPF MVVM project. A DataGrid shows the records found by a service. Each row has a button which executes an action with the record chosen.

```
public class ReferenceDossier
{
}
```

**XAML**

```
<GroupBox>
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBox>
                <TextBox.InputBindings>
                    <KeyBinding Key="Enter" Command="{Binding SearchCommand}"/>
                </TextBox.InputBindings>
            </TextBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</GroupBox>

<GroupBox>
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ReferenceDossiers}">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button Command="{Binding Command}"
                                                CommandParameter="{Binding}">>
                                    <iconPacks:PackIconFontAwesome Kind="PlusCircle" Foreground="#FF94bf00"/>
                                </Button>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</GroupBox>
```

When I make a search with the keyword in the `TextBox` and tap Enter, it performs a calculation and shows the results in `DataGrid`.

What I want to code:

If the user press ENTER again (after records shown on `DataGrid`) and the user hasn't selected yet a row, the `Command` of the `Button` of the first row must be invoked, not important how many records in the grid, the first one must be chosen.

If the user selects a row in `DataGrid` and press ENTER, the `Command` of the `Button` of that row is invoked.

If zero record, do nothing.

The goal is to reduce the time of chose on GUI.

But I can't find a way to do that by MVVM approach.

With some tries, when I press ENTER after tapping the keyword, `TextBox` is always focused. I press ENTER again, it reperforms the calculation.

Comment: Do you have any `ICommand` created for the button inside `CellTemplate`? How are you handling the *Tap* operation currently?

Comment: @dhilmathy of course, it has. I updated the question. Actually, it can be executed with a click by mouse

Comment: If executing the `Command` is the only requirement on `Button` *Tap*, why can't you call `Command.Execute(<firstItem>)` (after calculation) inside your `ViewModel` itself.

Comment: I updated the question. Hope it more clear for you.

Comment: So if the user presses ENTER and there is only one record in the DataGrid, the Command of this record should be invoked? If there is zero records or more than one record, the SearchCommand should be invoked? Is that what you want?

Comment: I updated the question. sorry for my English that makes the confuse. The goal of the question is very simple.

Comment: Why don't you invoke it from the viewmodel? Bind SelectedItem property  of the DataGrid to an object property in the vm then check if selecteditem is null. If it's null fire the first element command from viewmodel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found:

Following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1356781/6230863), we can set focus to control by a custom Property `IsFocused`.

So I put this property to the button, set true for the property if that is the first row and bind the Enter `InputBinding`

```
public class ReferenceDossier : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private bool _selected;
        public bool Selected
        {
            get
            {
                return _selected;
            }
            set
            {
                _selected = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Selected");
            }
        }
}
```

Set `Selected` for the first record to focus the button of the first row.

```
if(ReferenceDossiers.FirstOrDefault() != null)
                    ReferenceDossiers.First().Selected = true;
```

**XAML**

```
                     <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                                    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
                                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>                                        
                                </Style>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Button behaviors:FocusExtension.IsFocused="{Binding Selected}"
                                         Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type controls:MetroWindow}}, Path=DataContext.AddCommand}"
                                            CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                                        <Button.InputBindings>
                                            <KeyBinding Key="Enter" Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type controls:MetroWindow}}, Path=DataContext.AddCommand}"
                                            CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                                        </Button.InputBindings>
                                        <iconPacks:PackIconFontAwesome Kind="PlusCircle" Foreground="#FF94bf00"/>
                                    </Button>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

To choose the button of others row by the Up/Down press, we should customize the Cell, if not, the `CellTemplate` is focused not the button and the ENTER press doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EventTrigger` to achieve this.

**XAML**

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <local:EnterDownEventTrigger EventName="KeyDown">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Command}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
        </local:EnterDownEventTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

As you want the `Command` to get invoked only on *Enter* key, you need to write custom `EventTrigger` for this.

**Custom Event Trigger for Enter Key**

```
using System.Windows.Interactivity;
public class EnterDownEventTrigger : EventTrigger 
{    
    public EnterDownEventTrigger() : base("KeyDown") { }

    protected override void OnEvent(EventArgs eventArgs) 
    {
        var e = eventArgs as KeyEventArgs;
        if (e != null && e.Key == Key.Enter)
            this.InvokeActions(eventArgs);
    }
}
```

Reference the assembly: *System.Windows.Interactivity.dll*

Comment: Looks at my updated question pls. I think your answer will never work because the  DataGrid is never focused.