# WPF: Conditionally put focus on checkbox and button

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to set focus on conditionally in a `WPF`form. Here I have two types of control. One is 'checkbox' and other one is `button`. The `checkboxes` are getting enabled on some condition, however the `button` control(s) are visible by default. I am able to put focus on `button`(s) whether `checkboxes` are getting enabled or not. Though `checkboxes` should get focus over `button` when `checkboxes` are getting enabled.  Kindly, suggest an approach to achieve this please. I have used following code to achieve focus on `button`(s)

```
<Style x:Key="FocusElement" TargetType="Grid">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=chkCA, Path=IsVisible}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement" Value="{Binding ElementName=chkCA}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=btnSaveAll, Path=IsVisible}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement" Value="{Binding ElementName=btnSaveAll}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

Thanks!

Comment: @Sinatr Is this comment hints about the solution in the form of Attached behavior or a discussion further?

Comment: You say "better", which implies approach is working. But how better? Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1356781/1997232) better?

Comment: Oh, I got it now! Though, I want guidance to do this task of throwing focus. I have improved my question. I hope, you may provide me your valuable guidance to solve this puzzle, now.

Comment: Have you tried `BindingPriority` [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-implement-prioritybinding)?