# How to use the ".isFocused" property of my entry in the ViewModel?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

In my MainPage I am using a Custom Control which is an Entry and 2 buttons. I need to use the ".isFocused" property for the Entry in the ViewModel to do something, how can I do it?

I must get x:Name of the entry? I dont know can I do this, but I need to use .isFocused for the entry,so that when I click on the entry, a menu that I have is closed.

My Code:

CustomContol.xaml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ContentView
    x:Class="Aname.Xamarin.UIControls.Controls.CKEditor"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Name="CKEditorView">
    <ContentView.Content>

        <StackLayout>



            <Frame
                Margin="0,0,0,2"
                Padding="0,0,0,0"
                BackgroundColor="White"
                BorderColor="{Binding BorderColor}"
                CornerRadius="{Binding CornerRadius}"
                HasShadow="False">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


                    <ImageButton
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Margin="10,0,0,0"
                        BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                        Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference CKEditorView}, Path=BindingContext.EmojiCommand}"
                        HorizontalOptions="Start"
                        Source="{Binding LeftSideIcon}"
                        WidthRequest="30" />

                    <Entry
                        x:Name="EntryControl"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Margin="0,0,50,0"
                        HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                        Keyboard="Chat"
                        Placeholder="{Binding Placeholder}"
                        Text="{Binding EntryText}"
                        TextColor="Black" />
                    <ImageButton
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Margin="0,0,10,0"
                        BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                        Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference CKEditorView}, Path=BindingContext.SendCommand}"
                        HorizontalOptions="End"
                        Source="{Binding Source={x:Reference CKEditorView}, Path=RightSideIcon}"
                        WidthRequest="35" />


                </Grid>
            </Frame>


            <Frame Margin="0,-8,0,0" IsVisible="{Binding Source={x:Reference CKEditorView}, Path=BoxVisible}">
                <CollectionView
                    Margin="-10,-15,-10,-10"
                    HeightRequest="250"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Reference CKEditorView}, Path=EmojiItemSource}"
                    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never">

                    <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                        <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Span="5" />
                    </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ImageButton
                                Padding="5"
                                BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference CKEditorView}, Path=BindingContext.MethodCommandEmoji}"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding EmojiMethodCommand}"
                                HeightRequest="44"
                                Source="{Binding EmojiSource}"
                                WidthRequest="44" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

                </CollectionView>
            </Frame>


        </StackLayout>

    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

MainPage.xaml:

```html
  <StackLayout AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,1,AutoSize,AutoSize" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional">
            <fav:CKEditor
                x:Name="entrycontrol"
                BorderColor="{Binding BorderColor}"
                BoxVisible="{Binding IsVisible}"
                CornerRadius="{Binding CornerRadius}"
                EmojiItemSource="{Binding EmojiList}"
                LeftSideIcon="{Binding LeftSideIcon}"
                Placeholder="{Binding Placeholder}"
                RightSideIcon="{Binding RightSideIcon}"
                Text="{Binding EntryText}" />
        </StackLayout>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set focus on TextBox in WPF from view model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356045/set-focus-on-textbox-in-wpf-from-view-model) Please see the accepted answer in that post, it should help. Also it would help to include your VM and what you've tried so we could actually help you further.

Comment: you can just bind `IsFocused` to a property in your VM, or use the `Focused` event

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use EventToCommand Behavior.

Define the following classes

```
public class EventToCommandBehavior : BehaviorBase<VisualElement>
{
    Delegate eventHandler;

    public static readonly BindableProperty EventNameProperty = BindableProperty.Create("EventName", typeof(string), typeof(EventToCommandBehavior), null, propertyChanged: OnEventNameChanged);
    public static readonly BindableProperty CommandProperty = BindableProperty.Create("Command", typeof(ICommand), typeof(EventToCommandBehavior), null);
    public static readonly BindableProperty CommandParameterProperty = BindableProperty.Create("CommandParameter", typeof(object), typeof(EventToCommandBehavior), null);
    public static readonly BindableProperty InputConverterProperty = BindableProperty.Create("Converter", typeof(IValueConverter), typeof(EventToCommandBehavior), null);

    public string EventName
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(EventNameProperty); }
        set { SetValue(EventNameProperty, value); }
    }

    public ICommand Command
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(CommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CommandProperty, value); }
    }

    public object CommandParameter
    {
        get { return GetValue(CommandParameterProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CommandParameterProperty, value); }
    }

    public IValueConverter Converter
    {
        get { return (IValueConverter)GetValue(InputConverterProperty); }
        set { SetValue(InputConverterProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override void OnAttachedTo(VisualElement bindable)
    {
        base.OnAttachedTo(bindable);
        RegisterEvent(EventName);
    }

    protected override void OnDetachingFrom(VisualElement bindable)
    {
        DeregisterEvent(EventName);
        base.OnDetachingFrom(bindable);
    }

    void RegisterEvent(string name)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
        {
            return;
        }

        EventInfo eventInfo = AssociatedObject.GetType().GetRuntimeEvent(name);
        if (eventInfo == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("EventToCommandBehavior: Can't register the '{0}' event.", EventName));
        }
        MethodInfo methodInfo = typeof(EventToCommandBehavior).GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredMethod("OnEvent");
        eventHandler = methodInfo.CreateDelegate(eventInfo.EventHandlerType, this);
        eventInfo.AddEventHandler(AssociatedObject, eventHandler);
    }

    void DeregisterEvent(string name)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
        {
            return;
        }

        if (eventHandler == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        EventInfo eventInfo = AssociatedObject.GetType().GetRuntimeEvent(name);
        if (eventInfo == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("EventToCommandBehavior: Can't de-register the '{0}' event.", EventName));
        }
        eventInfo.RemoveEventHandler(AssociatedObject, eventHandler);
        eventHandler = null;
    }

    void OnEvent(object sender, object eventArgs)
    {
        if (Command == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        object resolvedParameter;
        if (CommandParameter != null)
        {
            resolvedParameter = CommandParameter;
        }
        else if (Converter != null)
        {
            resolvedParameter = Converter.Convert(eventArgs, typeof(object), null, null);
        }
        else
        {
            resolvedParameter = eventArgs;
        }

        if (Command.CanExecute(resolvedParameter))
        {
            Command.Execute(resolvedParameter);
        }
    }

    static void OnEventNameChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var behavior = (EventToCommandBehavior)bindable;
        if (behavior.AssociatedObject == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        string oldEventName = (string)oldValue;
        string newEventName = (string)newValue;

        behavior.DeregisterEvent(oldEventName);
        behavior.RegisterEvent(newEventName);
    }
}
```

And

```
public class BehaviorBase<T> : Behavior<T> where T : BindableObject
{
    public T AssociatedObject { get; private set; }

    protected override void OnAttachedTo(T bindable)
    {
        base.OnAttachedTo(bindable);
        AssociatedObject = bindable;

        if (bindable.BindingContext != null)
        {
            BindingContext = bindable.BindingContext;
        }

        bindable.BindingContextChanged += OnBindingContextChanged;
    }

    protected override void OnDetachingFrom(T bindable)
    {
        base.OnDetachingFrom(bindable);
        bindable.BindingContextChanged -= OnBindingContextChanged;
        AssociatedObject = null;
    }

    void OnBindingContextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OnBindingContextChanged();
    }

    protected override void OnBindingContextChanged()
    {
        base.OnBindingContextChanged();
        BindingContext = AssociatedObject.BindingContext;
    }
}
```

#### in Custom Control

```
<StackLayout>
            <Entry
                        x:Name="EntryControl"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Margin="0,0,50,0"
                        HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                        Keyboard="Chat"
                        Placeholder="{Binding Placeholder}"
                        Text="{Binding EntryText}"
                        TextColor="Black" >

                <Entry.Behaviors>
                    <local:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="Focused" Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference CKEditorView},Path=FocusedCommand}" CommandParameter="True"/>
                    <local:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="Unfocused" Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference CKEditorView},Path=FocusedCommand}" CommandParameter="False"/>
                </Entry.Behaviors>

            </Entry>
        </StackLayout>
```

```
public static readonly BindableProperty FocusedCommandProperty =
                   BindableProperty.Create(nameof(FocusedCommand), typeof(ICommand), typeof(CKEditor));

public ICommand FocusedCommand
{
   get => (ICommand)GetValue(FocusedCommandProperty);
   set => SetValue(FocusedCommandProperty, value);
}
```

#### in ContentPage

```
 <local:CKEditor  FocusedCommand="{Binding FocusedCommand}" />
```

#### in ViewModel

```
public ICommand FocusedCommand { get; set; }
```

```
FocusedCommand = new Command((arg)=> {

    bool isFocused = (bool)arg;
            
    if(isFocused)
    {
         //focused
    }

    else
    {
       //unfocused
    }
});
```